# Where should I ask general questions about electronics including information technology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

For example, the difference between two types of drives that are similar but not the same.
Another example. The difference between two different types of processor architecture types that resemble each other but are not the same.
Turns out electronics.stackexchange.com is not the site for that. It's for people that build electronics I think, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Learn to google with 'site:'. For IT you'll find Q&A in [so], [dba.se] & [cs.se] among others. PS "difference between" is almost always a pretend question. Abstracting how? You ask about multiple things. If you don't know what they are, why are you asking for "the difference"?--Find out what each is. If you think you know what they are, how is it that you need us to give "the difference"?--and what does that even mean? Either way give definitions, show & apply research & ask 1 clear specific non-duplicate question about how you are stuck on a specific point.

Comment: Asking questions about different hard drives is quite different from asking about processor architectures. The former is a consumer electronics question, the latter could be that too, but it can also be programming or electrical engineering. Questions about the differences of CPU cores may be on topic on several sites.

Comment: Or hybrid-flash array.

Comment: Difference between racetrack memory and magnetoresistive RAM for example.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your question, you are asking about computer architecture. So the best site to ask about that would be [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). A site for questions about:

- computer hardware
- computer software
- personal and home computer networking

If it's similar to that but not quite (like Corporate Networking or commercial Electrical Engineering issues): [SuperUser also has a list for "almost SU" topics.](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/855/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions)